# How to convert Categorical Data type into numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I have tried with this code. The output is: `Categorical(probs: torch.Size([12])))`. I want to extract the values from output and convert it into `numpy` array. Could anyone give a suggestion?

I know I can return the value of a (which is commented). But still, Is there any solution?

```
class Actor(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, state_size, action_size):
    super(Actor, self).__init__()
    self.state_size = state_size
    self.action_size = action_size
    self.linear1 = nn.Linear(self.state_size, 128)
    self.linear2 = nn.Linear(128, 256)
    self.linear3 = nn.Linear(256, self.action_size)

def forward(self, state):
    output = F.relu(self.linear1(state))
    output = F.relu(self.linear2(output))
    output = self.linear3(output)
    distribution = Categorical(F.softmax(output, dim=-1))
    # a=F.softmax(output, dim=-1)
    # print(a.detach().numpy())
    return distribution

    output=Actor(state)
    print(output)
```

Comment: we need to see the definition of `Categorical` class.

Comment: The class definition is available in this file

" from torch.distributions import Categorical "

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
prob = output.probs.detach().cpu().numpy()
```

Comment: Bit more explanation on these methods would be helpful?

Comment: The class was taken from "from torch.distributions import Categorical "